# Using urltools::url_parse with UTF-8 domains

Tags: r, url-parsing

The function `url_parse` is very fast and works fine most of the time. But recently, domain names may contain UTF-8 characters, for example

```
url <- "www.cordes-tiefkühlprodukte.de"
```

Now if I apply `url_parse` on this url, I get a special character "< fc >" in the domain column:

```
url_parse(url)
  scheme                            domain port path parameter fragment
1   <NA> www.cordes-tiefk<fc>hlprodukte.de <NA> <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
```

My question is: How can I "fix" this entry to UTF-8? I tried `iconv` and some functions from the `stringi` package, but with no success.

(I am aware of `httr::parse_url`, which does not have this problem. So one approach would be to detect the urls that are not ascii, and use `url_parse` on those and `parse_url` on the few special cases. However, this leads to the problem to (efficiently) detect the non-ascii URLs.)

EDIT: Unfortunately, `url1 <- URLencode(enc2utf8(url))` does not help. When I do

```
robotstxt::paths_allowed(
    url1, 
    domain=urltools::suffix_extract(urltools::domain(url1))
)
```

I get an error `could not resolve host`. However, plugging in the original URL and the 2nd level domain by hand, `paths_allowed` works.

```
> sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] urltools_1.7.3 fortunes_1.5-4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1  Rcpp_1.0.1      triebeard_0.3.0

Comment: I don't get the special character which you showed when I do `url <- "www.cordes-tiefkühlprodukte.de";urltools::url_parse(url)`.  The `domain` column shows as `www.cordes-tiefkühlprodukte.de` which is same as `url`. My R version is `R version 3.5.2` and `packageVersion("urltools") ‘1.7.3’`. You might want to update the post with your `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with my LOCALE?

Comment: I also get the special character. Does this solve your problem: `URLencode(enc2utf8(url))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue. I could convert the column `domain` to UTF-8 by reading it with `readr::parse_character` and `latin1` encoding:

```
library(urltools)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "www.cordes-tiefkühlprodukte.de"

parts <- 
  url_parse(url) %>% 
  mutate(domain = parse_character(domain, locale = locale(encoding = "latin1")))

parts

  scheme                         domain port path parameter fragment
1   <NA> www.cordes-tiefkühlprodukte.de <NA> <NA>      <NA>     <NA>
```

I guess that the encoding you have to specify (here `latin1`) depends only on your locale and not on the url's special characters, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, another method that works fine for me is:

```
library(stringi)
url <- "www.cordes-tiefkühlprodukte.de"
url <- stri_escape_unicode(url)
dat <- urltools::parse_url(url)
for(cn in colnames(dat)) dat[,cn] <- stri_unescape_unicode(dat[,cn])
```